# Question marks showing up while trying to reference equation

Tags: cross-referencing, ntheorem

Similar questions have been asked, but I've found them to be of no help. When I try to reference an equation in texstudio, all I get is ?? An example of code I have inserted which does this (I have taken this from Wikipedia) is:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:solve}
x^2 - 5 x + 6 = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_1 = \frac{5 + \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 6}}{2} = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_2 = \frac{5 - \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 6}}{2} = 2
\end{equation}

and so we have solved equation ~\ref{eq:solve}
```

Instead of it displaying a number I just get `??`, and yes I've compiled more than once.

For completeness I'll include the beginning of my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremsymbol{$\square$}
\newtheorem*{proof}{Proof}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{prop}{section}
\numberwithin{corollary}{section}
\numberwithin{lemma}{section}
```

Comment: Well you'll need to compile at least *twice* for see the equation reference right in your document. In the other hand according to your preamble you can use `\eqref` instead of `\ref`. In this way you'll get automatically the equation label inside parenthesis in the case you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the option `amsmath` (in addition to the option `thmmarks`) when loading the `ntheorem` package. (See also section 3.2.1 of the user guide of the `ntheorem` package.)

Comment: Oh, thank you, I just switched [thmmarks] for [thmmarks,amsmath] and it worked!